# Using AsyncTask to update UI in Android

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I'm trying to use asynctask to read about 1000 lines from SQLite. I'm also using a progressdialog to show the progress. Everything is working fine and when I get into the method onPostExecute() I dismiss the dialog and try to update the entire lines on the main thread. The dialog disappears but the UI takes a lot to update.
During the doInBackground() method, I'm filling a tablelayout and return it to onPostExecute().
How can I show the progressdialog until the main thread is totally filled?

```
private class FillTable extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, TableLayout>{
        private File file;
        private ProgressDialog pleaseWaitDialog;
        private Context ctx;
        private int colCount;
        private int linCount;
        private ScrollView scroolView;
        private SQLiteDatabase db;
        private Cursor cursor;


        public FillTable(Context context, String newQuery){
            ctx = context;
            scroolView = (ScrollView)ServiceActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.sv_service_vertical);

            file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + getResources().getString(R.string.DATABASE_PATH), getResources().getString(R.string.DATABASE_NAME));
            if(!file.exists()) {
                Toast.makeText(ctx, "Base de dados inválida ou não existe!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                this.cancel(true);
            }

            db = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(file, null);
            cursor = db.rawQuery(newQuery, null);

            pleaseWaitDialog = new ProgressDialog(ctx);
            pleaseWaitDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pleaseWaitDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute(){

            scroolView.removeAllViews();

            colCount = cursor.getColumnCount();
            linCount = cursor.getCount();

            pleaseWaitDialog.setMax(linCount);
            pleaseWaitDialog.setTitle("A ler a base de dados");
            pleaseWaitDialog.setMessage("Por favor aguarde...");
            pleaseWaitDialog.show();

            TextView tv = new TextView(ServiceActivity.this);
            tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
            tv.setText("A apresentar resultados.\nPode demorar algum tempo!\n\nPor favor aguarde...");
            ((ScrollView)ServiceActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.sv_service_vertical)).addView(tv);

            ((TextView)ServiceActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.tv_service_num_entradas)).setText("");
        }


        @Override
        protected TableLayout doInBackground(Void... params) {

            TableLayout tableLayout = null;

            if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {

                tableLayout = new TableLayout(ServiceActivity.this);

                //Preenchimento dos nomes das colunas
                TextView textView;
                TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(ServiceActivity.this);

                for (int i = 0; i < colCount; i++) {

                    textView = new TextView(ServiceActivity.this);

                    if (i == 0)
                        textView.setText(cursor.getColumnName(i));
                    else
                        textView.setText("\t" + cursor.getColumnName(i));

                    textView.setTextColor(Color.MAGENTA);
                    tableRow.addView(textView);
                }

                tableLayout.addView(tableRow);

                //Preenchimento das restantes linhas e das colunas de cada linha
                int k = 1;//a contar com o cabeçalho
                do {

                    this.publishProgress(k);
                    tableRow = new TableRow(ServiceActivity.this);

                    for (int i = 0; i < colCount; i++) {
                        textView = new TextView(ServiceActivity.this);
                        textView.setTextSize(11);
                        textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                        String str = cursor.getString(i);

                        if(str == null) {
                            if (i == 0)
                                textView.setText("...");
                            else
                                textView.setText("\t" + "...");
                        }
                        else{
                            if (i == 0)
                                textView.setText(str);
                            else
                                textView.setText("\t" + str);
                        }

                        textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                        tableRow.addView(textView);
                    }

                    tableLayout.addView(tableRow);
                    k++;

                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }

            db.close();
            cursor.close();

            return tableLayout;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress){
            pleaseWaitDialog.setProgress(progress[0].intValue());
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final TableLayout tl){

            scroolView.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    scroolView.removeAllViews();
                    scroolView.addView(tl);
                    ((TextView)ServiceActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.tv_service_num_entradas)).setText("Nº de entradas: " + String.valueOf(linCount));
                }
            });

            if(pleaseWaitDialog.isShowing())
                pleaseWaitDialog.dismiss();
        }


        @Override
        protected void onCancelled(final TableLayout tl){
            if(pleaseWaitDialog.isShowing())
                pleaseWaitDialog.dismiss();
            ((TextView)ServiceActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.tv_service_num_entradas)).setText("Nº de entradas: 0");
            scroolView.removeAllViews();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have been used AsyncTask for update UI Thread -> That fine.
But I seem you used AsyncTask wrong way.

**If you want display progress dialog util main thread (UI thread) filled**:

Define: [YourClassToDoTask] extends AsyncTask<[ValueInput], [ValueUpdate], [ValueOutput]>

[ValueUpdate] : is object of line which you want to update to UI.

**Use 3 methods**:  doInBackground, onProgressUpdate, onPostExecute

1. doInBackground: do long task in background to get data from any source, update to main thread by method **publishProgress([ValueUpdate])**
2. onProgressUpdate: Update value to UI Thread which got after doInBackground called  **publishProgress([ValueUpdate])**

   onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) -> [ValueUpdate] is array or   single object

   if array: [ValueUpdate] = progress

   if single object: [ValueUpdate] = progress[0]
3. onPostExecute: Dismis progressdialog (in here, UI thread total filled)

Comment: I think I understood what you mean but I've tried to update the main thread with tablerows instead of the entire tablelayout but the progressdialog blocks several times during the updates. Did you see the code I updated?

Comment: I seen your code. You should update tablerow in onProgressUpdate, shouldn't update in doinBackground and Why did you unuse ListView instead TableLayout? ListView make your UI become smooth

Comment: Ok. I'll try to update tablerow in onProgressUpdate() and I may change to listview. As soon as I get it done I will tell you something. Thank you.